# Como isolar metadados específicos num arquivo .ris?

Tags: r

Tenho um arquivo.ris com informações sobre pesquisadores e com algumas milhares de linhas. Cada pesquisador é identificado com um conjunto de metadados (estes são padronizados). Quero saber como faço para isolar metadados específicos nesse arquivo?

Gostaria de obter as informações "NOME" e "ENDE". Estou usando o Notepad++ e tentei subir o arquivo no RStudio, mas não tive sucesso em separar a informação com nenhum dos programas.

(Cada pesquisador tem mais ou menos 39 conjuntos de dados, mas nem todos os pesquisadores tem o mesmo número de metadados)

Exemplo da disposição dos dados no Arquivo RIS:

TY  - Membro

NOME  - Fulano

ENDE  - Endereço do fulano

ID01  - Primeiro idioma do fulano

...

< pula uma linha >

TY  - Membro

NOME  - Nome do beltrano

ENDE  - Endereço do beltrano

... (e por aí vai)